# Is there a /dev/video0 like default for pc-microphones?

Tags: pipe, udev, microphone

So, I've been playing with bash scripting on Linux and attempting to level up my terminal wizardry. I've learned about piping data from /dev/video0 for web cams, and quickly creating image files from it, in a few different ways.

Next up, I'm wondering if I can do the same with audio. It seems like it must be possible, and perhaps relatively easy; but I can't find any reference (using udev) to which device file data would be piped from.

Does such a device exist? How would I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sound in Linux is based on alsa: no user space nodes for audio stream like /dev/video0.
You can do some piping though: If you want to dig into this: two keywords: alsa, pipeline.

Have fun!